# OO Style Arguments in Elixir?

Tags: javascript, oop, erlang, arguments, elixir

How can I pass the self parameter in Elixir in an OO like way?

For example I wrote this Erlang Javascript like object with garbage collection:

```
-module(o).

-export([n/0, g/2, s/3, d/1]).

-behaviour(gen_server).
-export([init/1, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2, handle_info/2, terminate/2, code_change/3]).

-record(state, {dictionary=dict:new()}).

-define(SERVER, ?MODULE).

-on_load(deps/0).

deps() ->
    AS = fun(Mod) ->
        try application:start(Mod) catch _Type:_What -> ok end
    end,
    [AS(Mod) || Mod <- [sasl, lager, resource]],
    ok.

n() ->
    case gen_server:start(?MODULE, {}, []) of
        {ok, Pid} ->
            Res = resource:notify_when_destroyed(Pid, {timeout, Pid}),
            {?MODULE, {Res, Pid}};
        Other ->
            Other
    end.

g(Key, {?MODULE, {_Res, Pid}}) ->
    gen_server:call(Pid, {g, Key}).

s(Key, Val, {?MODULE, {_Res, Pid}}) ->
    gen_server:cast(Pid, {s, Key, Val}).

d({?MODULE, {_Res, Pid}}) ->
    gen_server:cast(Pid, stop).

%% @private
init({}) ->
    {ok, #state{}}.

%% @private
handle_call({g, Key}, _From, State = #state{dictionary=Dict}) ->
    {reply, case dict:find(Key, Dict) of {ok, Val} -> Val; error -> error end, State};
handle_call(Request, _From, State) ->
    lager:info("handle_call discarded request: ~p", [Request]),
    {reply, {error, unknown_call}, State}.

%% @private
handle_cast({s, Key, Value}, State = #state{dictionary=Dict}) ->
    {noreply, State#state{dictionary=dict:store(Key, Value, Dict)}};
handle_cast(stop, State) ->
    {stop, normal, State};
handle_cast(Msg, State) ->
    lager:info("handle_cast discarded message: ~p", [Msg]),
    {noreply, State}.

%% @private
handle_info({timeout, Pid}, State) ->
    d({?MODULE, {res, Pid}}),
    lager:info("Garbage collection of object ~p", [Pid]),
    {noreply, State};
handle_info(Info, State) ->
    lager:info("handle_info discarded message: ~p", [Info]),
    {noreply, State}.

%% @private
terminate(_Reason, _State) ->
    ok.

%% @private
code_change(_OldVsn, State, _Extra) ->
    {ok, State}.
```

NOTE: I use https://github.com/tonyrog/resource.git for resource collection.

```
1> l(o).
... LOGS ...
{module,o}
2> O = o:n().
{o,{{resource,140524043665312,<<>>},<0.58.0>}}
3> O:s(a, b).
ok
4> O:g(a).
b
6> O:s(hello, fun() -> io:format("Hello World~n") end). 
ok
7> (O:g(hello))().
Hello World
ok
```

Comment: It is possible to write the same code in Elixir, by passing the "object" as last argument but it is highly discouraged in both Erlang and Elixir communities. It would be more interesting to know which problem is being solved. The usage of `resource` is highly uncommon too.

Comment: @JoséValim I know I wanted to see if it was technically possible have a mutable javascript like object in Erlang. Mostly because someone said it wasn't possible.

Comment: Yes, so it is possible similar to how you wrote it. You can do a literal translation to Elixir of your Erlang code same and it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware it's not possible to call modules in this way in Elixir. You must explicitly pass the self parameter for all of the calls. So to take your Erlang example to Elixir, it would look like:

```
iex> o = O.n()
{O, {{:resource, 140524043665312, <<>>}, <0.58.0>}}
iex> O.s(:a, :b, o)
:ok
iex> O.g(:a, o)
:b
...
```

Someone else can chime in and correct me here, but I haven't seen the OO-like access that you demonstrated here in any of the Elixir code I've seen.